# Connect 2 computers remotely

Tags: networking, 15.10

I'd like to know how to connect 2 Ubuntu computers a desktop and a laptop so that from the laptop remotely i can use sudo permission on the desktop

Comment: Are you referring to remote GUI (like RDP in Windows) or just to execute commands? If so, you can always use SSH to do such

Comment: Apart from all, You can use [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/hi/download/linux.aspx)...  Its descent enough ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a remote desktop server on your desktop pc (`vino-server`) and connect to it with `remmina` on your laptop.  You will be able to do anything on the desktop that you could do if you were sitting there.

If all you want is command line access, as [AzkerM](https://askubuntu.com/users/179042/azkerm) stated in a comment, you can run an `ssh` server on the desktop and connect to it from your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what is mentioned in the above answer.
One can use Vino without encryption also

```
install dconf-tools:

sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

start dconf-editor from the command line and go to org->gnome->desktop->remote-access and toggle the require-encryption item to unchecked.

If desktop sharing was enabled prior to changing the setting, then execute the following from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

If desktop sharing was not enabled prior to changing the setting, then enable desktop sharing.